# How to remove a selected item from a dropdown list (Using Jquery)

Tags: jquery

How to remove one or more selected items in option tag, from a HTML dropdown list (Using Jquery).

For removing entire options from a combo box we can use the below Jquery statement.

$("#cmbTaxIds >option").remove();

Assuming the below HTML code in aspx file.

```
            <select id="cmbTaxID" name="cmbTaxID" style="width: 136px; display: none" tabindex="10" disabled="disabled">
                <option value="0"></option>
                <option value="3"></option>
                <option value="1"></option>
            </select>
```

If I want to remove only the middle value, then what should be the syntax for the same (using Jquery)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector.

```
var index = $('#cmbTaxID').get(0).selectedIndex;
$('#cmbTaxID option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
```

This is the best way to do it because it's index-based, not arbitrary value-based.

Answer (score 16):

To remove the selected item:

```
$("#cmbTaxID :selected").remove();
```

Comment: I didn't use `option` and it worked for me. Am I missing something if I use - `$("#cmbTaxID :selected").remove();` ?

Comment: It will work. It will look for a element with the SELECTED attribute inside the <SELECT>. Since you should only have <OPTION>s in there, I don't see any problem using your code.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 7):

something like this:

```
$('#cmbTaxID option:selected').remove();
```

or even shorter:

```
$('#cmbTaxID :selected').remove();
```

Comment: This seems the most elegant to me. The selector will find all the selected options. The other solutions involve passing an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#cmbTaxIds >option[value='3']").remove();
```

Just replace `3` with the value of the element you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic answer to remove the selected option could be

```
$('#somebutton').click(function(){
    var optionval = $('#cmbTaxIds').val();
    $('#cmbTaxIds > option[value=' + optionval + ']').remove();

})
```