# Don't show default selected option in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to not show the first option inside the dropdown list of a HTML select tag? They only thing I know of is to disable it from being clicked but I want it to not be shown inside the dropdown, like this :

[image: example]

```
<select class="archive" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">..după lună:</option>
    <option value="#">Ianuarie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Februarie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Martie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Aprilie 2015</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Arvind , I have no limitations, I already use jquery in this website but can I achieve this using jquery? Considering that I only need to not show the first option inside the list but I need it to show up in the box, just like in the image I posted :)

Comment: Did you tryed to set css visibility to "none"?

Comment: @bitifet I just answered my own question. Apparently adding style="display:none;" to the first option will not hide it from the box itself, just from the list. I did not think of this cause I thought it will automatically hide it from both the list and the box.

Comment: You will find your answer in this post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413188/how-to-remove-a-selected-item-from-a-dropdown-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not think about trying CSS to achieve this cause I thought that by adding `style="display:none;"` to my first option tag will hide the value from the box too, but as it appears, it doesn't. You can achieve this by changing my initial code in the question with:

```
<select class="archive" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" style="display:none;">..lună:</option>
    <option value="#">Ianuarie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Februarie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Martie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Aprilie 2015</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, i believe what you are trying to do is this. Goodluck

```
$('.archive option:selected').hide(); //initialise
```

A much more dynamic approach for all selected elements is below:

```js
$(function(){
   $('.archive option:selected').hide(); //initialise
  
   $('.archive').change(function(){
     
     $('.archive option').show(200, function(){
       
         $('.archive option:selected').hide();
       
     });
     
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="archive">
    <option selected="selected">..după lună:</option>
    <option value="#">Ianuarie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Februarie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Martie 2015</option>
    <option value="#">Aprilie 2015</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, that IS what I was trying to achieve but if you will look at the answer I posted you will see that I managed to achieve it by simple adding a line of CSS.There's really no need of using jquery for this ....

Comment: Also, I did not need to hide every selected value, just the default one.

Comment: I assume your first default value signifies to users to select an item from the list. The problem with your solution is the fact that the first item will disappear forever and there will never be an empty entry for the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('.archive option:selected').hide(); //initialise
  
   $('.archive').change(function(){
     
     $('.archive option').show(200, function(){
       
         $('.archive option:selected').hide();
       
     });
     
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="archive">
    <option selected="selected">..după lună:</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.