# How to hide selected text of SELECT(Dropdown)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

We want to display Dropdown items when click on dropdown. And need to set text of selected item in Textbox, We done with it using onchange event. 
But we do not want to display selected text of dropdown in dropdown;s textbox itself.
We are using dropdown reverse triangle option in front of Textbox to perform necessary logic.
Is it possible to hide dropdown selected text?

Comment: code? ! please update your question with your codes

Comment: @jiff I have checked several options for same, so no concrete option to showcase here. I just want to ask that is there any way to Hide selected text of dropdown?

Comment: you can put your code here via `code snippet` or `JSFiddle.net` or `codepen.io` we should see your codes then help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3413220/4229270

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent shared any code assuming few thing I have created a fiddle.. kindly check http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/848/

all you need to do is after selecting an item from dropdown reset the dropdown

**HTML**

```
<select id="name" >
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="Text 1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="Text 2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="Text 3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="txt">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#name').change(function(){
    var x=$('#name').val();
    console.log(x);
    $('.txt').val(x);
    $('#name').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
});
```